# Check if two arrays share any common keys

Tags: php

What's the best way to check if at least one key of an array exists in another?

This means, I want to find out if two arrays share any keys in common, and return true if this is so for at least one key.

```
$required = array('red', 'blue');

$colours = array(
    'red' => 'one',
    'blue' => 'two',
    'green' => 'three'
);
```

If the `red` key was found in the `$colours` array, it would still return true, just as it would if they both were present.

I have looked at examples, but they seem to check if ALL keys are present, or checking if just one key exists. I could use array_key_exists many times and use `if (.. || ..)`, but I would like to use another array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php). If the resulting array has more than 0 items, then they had keys in common.

Since `$required` only contains values, you can use [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to create an array with colour keys from it.

When you combine all of it, you can write something like this:

```
$required = array('red', 'blue');

$colours = array(
    'red' => 'one',
    'blue' => 'two',
    'green' => 'three'
);

if (count($intersection = array_intersect_key($colours, array_flip($required))) > 0)
{
  echo 'They have the keys ' . implode(',', array_keys($intersection)) . ' in common';
}
```

You can even take advantage from the fact that `array_intersect_key` returns the intersecting keys with the values from the *first* array, that is, the array that is passed in the first parameter.

So, if you want to display the keys and values, this is possible as well (split up a little, to make it slightly more readable).

```
$required = array('red', 'orange', 'green');

$colours = array(
    'red' => 'one',
    'blue' => 'two',
    'green' => 'three'
);

// Convert required colours to keys
$requiredKeys = array_flip($required);

// Get the intersection. Pass in `$colours` first if you want the values too.
$intersection = array_intersect_key($colours, $requiredKeys);

if (count($intersection) > 0)
{
  // Get and display the matching keys.
  $matchingKeys = array_keys($intersection);
  echo 'They have the keys "' . implode('","', $matchingKeys) . '" in common. ';

  // And the corresponding values.
  echo 'Relating to the values "' . implode('","', $intersection) . '". ';
}
```

Comment: It's `array_intersect_key` (no 's').

Comment: @RocketHazmat I typed it wrong again when I added a code sample. Apparently it's wrong in my head. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: I figured it was just a typo, so I fixed it for you :)

Answer (score 2):

use array_keys (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with array_intersect (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: Or even `array_intersect_key`.

Answer (score 2):

This is sample code from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'green'  => 3, 'purple' => 4);
$array2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 6, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);

var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2));
?>
```

This should give you the intersection of the 2 arrays which have common keys.

Answer (score 1):

`array_intersect_key` — Computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison

**usage**

```
array array_intersect_key ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
```

**`array_intersect_key()`** returns an array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all the arguments.